# Align scanned documents based on a reference point, using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently trying to write a program that can automatically extract data from some graphs in multiple scanned documents. Mainly by using opencv I would like to detect some features of the graphs in order to convert them into usable data. In the left graph I'm looking for the height of the circle sectors and in the right graph the distance from the center to the points where the dotted lines intersect with the gray area. In both cases I would like to convert these values into numeric data for further usage.

[image]

What follows is a step by step plan of how I think my algorithm will work:

1. Align the image based on the big dotted lines. This way I can ensure that the graphs in all the scanned images will have the exact same positions. After all, it is possible that some images will be slightly tilted or moved in comparison with other images, due to the manual scanning process. Basically I want the coordinate of a pixel in one image to correspond to the exact same pixel in another image.
2. We now know that the coordinates of the graph centers and the angles for the circle sectors are identical for all images now. For each circle sector, filter the darker pixels from the lighter ones. This is done using the openCV `inRange` function.
3. Search for the best fitting segment over the darker pixels in the left graph and search for the best fitting triangle in the right graph. This is done by global optimization.
4. Return the radius of the optimal segment and return the edge lengths of the optimal triangle. Now we have values that we can use as data.

I have more or less figured out how to do every step, except the first one. I have no clue on how I would go about aligning my images. Does someone might have an idea or a strategy on how to achieve this alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  canny, it give you perfect long edge. If this is the only part you dont understand, here is the answer. You can adjust the parameter to get the best result. The first will be idea for both line and pie circle. But if you only keen to find pie. change the parameter accordingly to get my 2nd image

[image]

The red denotes the doted line. sample from opencv directly

[image]

Step 2: local area enhancement/segmentation to find both circles (from image 1 parameter with houghcircle param2 set to 110)

[image]

Step 3: Segment the pie out(all the way to the edge of image) and find the median line

Step 4: OCR on the test image pies and find the distance of none-background color along the median line.

Step 5: generate list out and send to csv or sth